# How to query customers data with different customer levels in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Currently, I encounter with running query in Posgtresql server, there are 3 tables which contain customer information, customers who apply membercard and customers payment as below:

1. table customer

   `customerid, name, lastname, age`
2. table payment

   `customerid, payment, product, date`
3. table membercard

   `customerid, membercardno, createddate, status`

In my system, there are 2 kind of customers such as regular and member customers.

- Regular customers are those customers that haven't applied to be member customers yet.
- Member customers are those customers that already applied to be customers.

In this scenario, I would like to query all of 2 kind customers in these 3 tables.
ex: customerid, name, lastname, age, membercardno, payment, product, date

For my query:

```
SELECT C.CUSTOMERID, C.NAME, C.LASTNAME, C.AGE,
       M.MEMBERCARDNO, P.PAYMENT, P.PRODUCT, P.DATE
  FROM CUSTOMER C,
       MEMBERCARD M,
       PAYMENT P
  WHERE C.CUSTOMERID = M.MEMBERCARD AND
       C.CUSTOMERID = P.CUSTOMERID
  ORDER BY CUSTOMERID
```

in this case, just can query only those customers are member customers.
How to query both kind of customers? it's very hard to do for me.

Any help from our expert will be very appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an OUTER JOIN to pull in the membercard data, because not all customers have a member card.

```
SELECT C.CUSTOMERID, C.NAME, C.LASTNAME, C.AGE,
       M.MEMBERCARDNO, P.PAYMENT, P.PRODUCT, P.DATE
  FROM CUSTOMER C
  LEFT OUTER JOIN MEMBERCARD M
    ON M.MEMBERCARD = c.CUSTOMERID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PAYMENT P
    ON P.CUSTOMERID = C.CUSTOMERID
  ORDER BY C.CUSTOMERID
```

An OUTER JOIN is an optional join - if the data exists in the root table but doesn't exist in the joined table it will still be returned. Contrast this with an INNER JOIN (which is what you were doing, although you probably didn't realize it) where matching data must exist in both tables of the join for results to be returned.

Also, get in the habit of using ANSI-style joins as shown above, instead of the old-style implicit joins as used in your original query. It's easier to understand what's going on with ANSI joins.

Best of luck.

Comment: Great!!! Perfect sir.
Thank you very much for your time and kindly help me.

Thanks,